# Scrapy splash multiple clicks

Tags: python, scrapy, splash-screen

I'm trying to scrape proxies from a website that uses **DataTables** plugin
for instance everything works alright except for one thing : the spider scrape first and second page and not moving on the rest of pages .

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest


class SpiderManSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'usproxy'

    script = """
        function main(splash)
            local url = splash.args.url
            assert(splash:go(url))
            assert(splash:wait(1))

            assert(splash:runjs("$('.next').click();"))
            assert(splash:wait(1))

            return splash:html()
        end
        """

    def start_requests(self):
        yield SplashRequest(url='http://us-proxy.org', endpoint='render.html', callback=self.parse, args={'wait': 1})

    def parse(self, response):
        for data in response.css("tr"):
            yield {
                'ip': data.css("td:nth-child(1)::text").extract_first()
            }

        if response.xpath("//a[@id='proxylisttable_next' and @class='ui-state-disabled']").extract_first():
            self.logger.warning("button is disabled")
        else:
            yield SplashRequest(url=response.url, endpoint='execute', args={'lua_source': self.script, 'wait': 1},
                                callback=self.parse)
```

The debugger shows that it's filterning all duplicate request so i added **don't_filter** to the **SplashRequest** which caused me an infinite loop showing the data only from the second page .

Comment: have you tried just doing another click after `splash:wait` call? i.e. `click -> wait ->click2 -> wait -> render`

Comment: @Granitosaurus as my code shows after every click i added splash:wait()

Comment: @Granitosaurus the problem that i'm running into is that the response blocks at the second page only it doesn't move forward to the other pages

Comment: oh, it seems like just running new request, it means new session is start for the splash. So you are connecting to splash twice and click next page every time only once.

Comment: @Granitosaurus yep that's what i was thinking about, would you suggest a  solution on how to fix the problem ?

Comment: You can try putting `splash:html()` results in an array and return that array in your lua script. For that you should use `render.json` instead of `render.html` since I think it can return multiple values, i.e. a list.

Comment: @Granitosaurus the problem is only with pagination for example : supponsig that we are at the first page when we click next (page 2) splash must preserve the response so it can forward to the third page. but in my case as you said everytime it opens a new instance .

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem.

It seems that when the `assert(splash:runjs("$('.next').click();"))` is executed, the html page to be return in the response is changed to new one, but response.url remains the same as the url of the initial request.

The possible solution is to change return statement in the script to:

```
return {
    splash:url(),
    splash:html(),
}
```